# Only_if with Loop in Ruby_block to pass Foodcritic FC022

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I've been trying to figure out the better approach to use condition inside a `ruby_block` to avoid **[FC022](http://www.foodcritic.io/#FC022)** rulewhen the code gets evaluated by Foodcritic.

> FC022: Resource condition within loop may not behave as expected

The code of mine is as follows

```
ruby_block 'file configuration' do
block do
  files = [
    '/etc/file01.conf',
    '/etc/file02.conf',
  ]

  files.each do |f|
    file = Chef::Util:FileEdit.new(f)
    file.insert_line_if_no_match('something', 'something')
    file.write_file
    only_if { ::File.exist?(f) }
  end
end
```

Removing `only_if` will pass **FC022** rule in Footcritic.

Comment: Have you tried to move `only_if` inside `each` loop? Outside of the loop, f should be nil. Unless it is declared outside ruby_block.

Comment: @SzymonSzypulski this does not work even everything is put inside a `ruby_block`. I updated the question btw.

Comment: Code should work the same, if you really care so much about FC you can move loop outside the resource `files.each do |f|; ruby_block "#{f} configuration" ....; end`